# calculating an integral of a density function over a given surface

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

I am having a hard time with this question and would love to get some help.
The question is:

> Calculate the mass of the surface:
>   $$
>     S = \left\{(x,y,z) : z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2},\ x \leq y \leq 4x -2 - x^2 \right\}
> $$
>   with density 
>   $$
>     \rho(x,y,z) = \frac{2z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
> $$

Comment: Hi, welcome.  I took the liberty of transcribing the math formulas you screencapped.  Can you edit the question to include how far you got before you encountered difficulty?  For instance, can you express the mass as an iterated integral?

Comment: hey thank you very much. actually im having a hard time with expressing it. im not even sure what is the right way to do it.. whether it is a surface integral of just 3 variable integral. i tried to just integrate by dy and then look on the XZ plane but it didnt work out

Comment: OK, I added an answer which outlines some important steps in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that $S$ is the graph of a function $g$ over a region $D$ in the $xy$-plane.  In situations like that, surface integrals of functions can be calculated as regular two-variable area integrals:
$$
    \iint_S \rho\,dS = \iint_D \rho(x,y,g(x,y)) \sqrt{1+g_x^2+g_y^2}\,dA
$$
The next thing to notice is that $D$ can be described as the region between the graphs of functions of $x$:
$$
    D = \left\{(x,y) : a \leq x \leq b,\ \phi_1(x) \leq y \leq \phi_2(x) \right\}
$$
In situations like that, area integrals can be calculated as iterated integrals:
$$
\iint_D \rho(x,y,g(x,y)) \sqrt{1+g_x^2+g_y^2}\,dA
= \int_a^b \int_{\phi_1(x)}^{\phi_2(x)}\rho(x,y,g(x,y))\sqrt{1+g_x^2+g_y^2}\,dy\,dx
$$
Now you “just” have to do these iterated integrals.  But for this particular $g$ and $\rho$ things work out pretty nicely.